# custom log4j layout class not being called

Tags: log4j

I've a custom log4j layout class that extends PatternLayout, my layout class simply masks the password in the log.  It works in a simple console app.  Here's the log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="A1" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
     <layout class="com.PortalLog4jFilteringPattern"> <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n"/> </layout> 
</appender>

<root> 
    <priority value ="DEBUG" /> <appender-ref ref="A1" /> 
</root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Here's a snipet of the layout class:

```
public class PortalLog4jFilteringPattern extends PatternLayout {
// omitted
@Override
public String format(LoggingEvent event) {
   System.out.println("in format()...... ");
// rest omitted
```

Here's the calling code:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

  public class ProductDemo {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ProductDemo.class);

    public ProductDemo() {
    }

    public void processOrder(CustomerOrder order) {
    logger.info(order.getProductName());
  }
// rest ommited
```

A sample result log with pswd being masked:

```
main INFO  test.ProductDemo - "password":"*****"},
```

But once I moved the custom layout class to my webapp (log4j.xml is exactly the same.), it doesn't get called (i.e., no System.out output) and the pswd is still being shown.  I'm running the webapp locally with maven on Jetty using this cmd: mvn jetty:run

Here's the calling code:

```
// original code, but I changed it to import org.apache.log4j.Logger for experiment
//import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
//import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class BlahBlahClass extends Blah
// things omitted

private final static Logger log = Logger.getLogger( BlahBlahClass .class );
```

Any idea?  thanks

Comment: Just a thought but perhaps Jetty is piping stdout somewhere else where you're not seeing it?

Answer (score 0):

In a Java EE server environment I would say: it's a class loader issue. Jetty is a servlet container, so it's class loading architecture is simpler; still, it's worth checking. If your log4j **is not** deployed within the WAR, but comes from the Jetty class path, this is almost certainly the cause.

Try changing the class loading strategy to "parent last", as described in [the Jetty manual](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Classloading), see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should import package name of your class in log4j. I added to log4j2.xml as below:

```
<Configuration  packages="package path of your class">
```